# Method returns my object objective c

Tags: objective-c

I have a class named myClass that contains 3 NSInteger and I can't do a method like that:

```
- (myClass)getClass {
    myClass *class1;
    return class1
}
```

it gives me an error

EDIT: the error is in the .h

```
- (myClass *)getClass; Error: expected ')' before 'myClass'
```

Comment: @Inerdia probably "Interface type 'myClass' cannot be returned by value."

Comment: No, "expected ')' before myClass"

Comment: Thank you so much, I was banging my head with the same error! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you want to return an instance of `myClass`. You can do that like this:

```
- (myClass *)getClass {
  myClass *class1 = [[[myClass alloc] init] autorelease];
  return class1;
}
```

If instead you want to return the class itself:

```
- (Class)getClass {
  return myClass;
}
```

You can change the `-` to a `+` if you want it to be a class method instead of an instance method. Your question wasn't quite clear.

---

In Objective-C you can never return an object by value, since the size of an object in Objective-C isn't known at compile time. If you don't like the asterisks everywhere you can do `typedef myClass* myClassRef` and return a `myClassRef` instead.

Comment: Thanks, but the error is in the .h an not in the .m. I had also errors in the .m, but I have write your first code and I have fixed them.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C, every class type is a reference type. So, the return type should be `myClass*`. When we have a pointer like -

```
int *ptr = new int; // The type of ptr is int* but not int. Same is the case for 
                        // class types too.
```

Comment: Yes I have write the -, but I'm going to try with *

Comment: That is C++, not Objective-C.

Comment: @WTP - I am pretty sure, that line compiles on Objective-C too. Please, check it. I might be wrong though :)

Comment: @Mahesh it doesn't. It only does if you compile as C++ or Objective-C++. In Objective-C you need to do `int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));`.

Comment: @WTP - Ok. Stand corrected. Let the example stand as a generic one to let OP know that type associated with **ptr** is **int***.

Answer (score 0):

Completing Mahesh response, you need do:

```
- (myClass*) getClass { 
   myClass *class1; 
   return class1; 
}
```

or if method is static, you need do:

```
+ (myClass*) getClass { 
   myClass *class1; 
   return class1; 
}
```